# How to display two custom tool windows in a same place as tabbed format

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I have created multiple custom tool windows in VSIX, similar to the ones described in this Microsoft Learn documentation. While the custom windows I built can open and dock at the desired positions, they do not display in a tabbed form. Instead, they show one on top of another. I want my custom tool windows to appear like the default tool windows in Visual Studio, such as Solution Explorer, Class View, and Git Changes, with the ability to switch between them in a tabbed format.

tried to set the tool window properties using the following code:

```
[ProvideToolWindow(typeof(Mytoolwindow), Style = VsDockStyle.Tabbed, DockedWidth = 300, Window = "DocumentWell", MultiInstances = true, Orientation = (ToolWindowOrientation)Tool.Bottom)]
[ProvideToolWindow(typeof(Mytoolwindow1), Style = VsDockStyle.Tabbed, DockedWidth = 300, Window = "DocumentWell", MultiInstances = true, Orientation = (ToolWindowOrientation)Tool.Bottom)]
```

However, my two tool windows are still displaying docked to the bottom position separately without being grouped together with a tabbed style. How can I resolve this issue? Note: I do not want to use any Visual Studio tool window names in the "Window" argument.